# minimal web design

Tags: html, css

I am interested in minimal design, from design (ie. minimalist design) and performance view points. I am trying out "zero images" approach at the moment.

(obviously no flash/silverlight/etc) pure html+css(+js)

Has anyone tried it, seen it, thought about it.

To give an example, craigslist would be minimalist design. It has 0 images, 1 css, 1 js.

StackOverflow is NOT minimal design (although it seems so).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think minimal design is a definitive, or explicit way of describing a website.  Personally I'd say SO is quite minimalist because it only has a few graphics, all of which are quite small.  It's subjective in my opinion.

Comment: stackoverflow's one image up top disqualifies it? (now that i look again, i see that there is another! the mail icon!!)

Comment: well, we aren't talking only about the first page. There are up/down arrows, stars, etc. You could make the first page look like http://ya.ru and still screw up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the [960](http://960.gs/demo.html) framework? It's pretty minimalist and works a treat. Obviously you can do away with the column images used for the demo, the rest is css and html.

Comment: http://www.thegridsystem.org/ This will blow your mind

Answer (score 5):

I've thought about it a lot over the last 13 years I've made websites.  I think it comes down to one thing. "What is the intent of the site?"  Depending on what the intent is, will drive what level of interactivity, level of complexity, depth of user interface required, and to your point, the amount of images required to fulfill the intent.

Comment: I completely agree, the site itself is not the goal, it´s just a means to an end. It´s the end that defines your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Google beat Altavista like 13 years ago.

Comment: exactly, google IS minimal design, yahoo/msn/etc are not

Comment: @pitra: but google still has images!

Comment: @pitra exactly which page are you comparing ?

Comment: You could pretty easily get very close to the google image without the image.

Answer (score 1):

Would creating applications that are not minimalist but that degrade gracefully be an option?  The big thing that a lot of customers want is "wow" factor and that is hard to achieve by being minimalistic.

Comment: I would actually be impressed by a clean minimalist design. If the layout is elegant and the right information is displayed, it beats all the flash candy hands down.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to minimalist, I love the [blog.txt](http://www.plaintxt.org/themes/blogtxt/blogtxt_01/) wordpress theme by plaintxt.org. Has nothing but a clean layout and good font combinations. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have to agree with dominicminicoopers on this one. You need to understand the intended target audence as well as the methods they'll use to access this site in order to know if it makes sense to use this type of style. If the site is to be used in small mobile devices or very slow internet connections then i could see why you'd like to reduce the amount of graphics and files. If, on the other hand, they will use higher speed connections, then why not make the site as attractive as possible? I'm not saying that graphics are essential to make any site atractive, but they certainly help.

Good Luck!

Andres